# Android Xml - LinearLayout with 3 textviews top, center and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to align 3 `TextView` inside a vertical `LinearLayout`. What I want to achieve is to have a one `TextView` at the top one at the center and another one at the bottom. However, when I set the margin for the bottom one the other two are moving the position. How can I achieve this like the example showed below?

WRONG
[image]

CORRECT 
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/img_circle_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="0dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/songDuration"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="songDuration"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_music_txt_circlefragment"
                    android:textSize="8dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/songName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="songName"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_music_txt_circlefragment"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buy_songs_player"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/buy_song_player"
                    android:textColor="#FB6763"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why u are not using Relativelayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your linear layout and try it with the following code.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/img_circle_background"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songDuration"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="songDuration"
        android:textColor="@color/default_music_txt_circlefragment"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/songName"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="songName"
        android:textColor="@color/default_music_txt_circlefragment"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buy_songs_player"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/buy_song_player"
        android:textColor="#FB6763"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Comment: This will not compile because you use the id 'songName' before defining it.

Comment: I have checked it in Android Studio and it shows preview properly.

Comment: thank you is working properly. And @HristoStoyanov it seems to compile perfectly